# Angular4 Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target on a empty line

Tags: angular

When i try to build my angular project i keep getting 
`ERROR in ng:///C:/.../e-front/src/app/_com
ponents/procurer-shopping-cart/procurer-shopping-cart.component.html (48,87): Su
pplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

But inside the actual file it is a empty line:

```
 46 <tbl-procurer-shopping-cart [shoppingCart]="shoppingCart" [parent]="thisParent" [showImage]="showImage"
 47  (onCheckAll)="checkAll($event)" (onCheckBox)="checkBox($event)" (onCopyItem)="copyItem($event)" (onRemoveItem)="removeItem($event)"></tbl-procurer-shopping-cart>
 48
```

ng serve is working fins as i can run the code in my local host, but the server wants to build it and then run it, but build keeps failing. What is causing this and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you methods: `checkAll`, `checkBox` etc do not match methods in your typescript component file. For example your method `checkAll` do not accept event as an argument. This causes an exception.

```
<component (onCheck)="checkAll($event)"></component>
...
checkAll(){
//code
}
```

This will write an error in aot mode as you've written. So check all the signatures of you handler methods to match callsite in html as you use them on output bindings.

Comment: Jep you were right. Weird thing is, that this piece of code has been working for months and now today it decided not to work anymore. I wish the error message would tell me which signature is broken.